# missfont, something wrong with font when I log in

Tags: 12.04, fonts

When I log in, the fonts are not displayed properly, and I get this file in home directory: `missfont.log`

```
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmti10
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmr10
mktextfm cmti10
mktextfm cmr10
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmti10
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmr10
mktextfm cmti10
mktextfm cmr10
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some fonts are missing. Try to install the cmti10 and the cmr10 fonts:

```
sudo apt-get install jsmath-fonts
```